# OpenGL - Rotations go the wrong direction

Tags: opengl

I have this part of code that draws a rectangular parallelepiped with colors on the faces so as to distinguish them.

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);     // To operate on model-view matrix
glLoadIdentity();                 // Reset the model-view matrix

glNewList(1, GL_COMPILE);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(-1, -1, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1, -1, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1, 1, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1, 1, 1.0f);
glEnd();
glEndList();

glTranslatef(0, 0, -50);

deg += 0.03;
glRotatef(deg, 0, 1, 0);

glScalef(10, 10, 20);

glColor3f(1, 0, 0); //red
glCallList(1);

glColor3f(1, 1, 0); //yellow
glRotatef(90, 0, 1, 0);
glCallList(1);

glColor3f(0, 1, 0); //green
glRotatef(90, 0, 1, 0);
glCallList(1);

glColor3f(0, 1, 1); //cyan
glRotatef(90, 0, 1, 0);
glCallList(1);

glColor3f(0, 0, 1); //blue
glRotatef(90, 1, 0, 0);
glCallList(1);

glColor3f(1, 0, 1); //magenda
glRotatef(180, 1, 0, 0);
glCallList(1);
```

This is also the callback for the idleFunc, so the object rotates all the time. My problem is that the rotates I use for drawing the object are reverse than they should. The front face is drawn red, but then the yellow one goes on the right side instead of the left, and the cyan goes on the left. The same happens for top and bottom (blue goes on bottom and magenda on top).

What makes it more strange is that the rotating that spins the whole object follows the right-hand rule as it is expected.

Comment: You may have to provide the reasoning for your expectation. Just looking at the yellow face, this sounds exactly as expected. The original face is placed on the positive z-axis. Then for the yellow face, you rotate 90 degrees around the y-axis. A 90 degree rotation around the y-axis rotates the positive z-axis to the positive x-axis. Which points to the right, so the yellow face ends up on the right.

Comment: Oh you're right. I was thinking it as the objects moving and the axis stay on their position, so I expected the red face to go to the x-axis and the left side come in front and paint yellow. I see my mistake now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I had the rotations wrong in my mind, as Reto Koradi stated in his comment. I was expecting the whole plane to rotate and send the cube on the right side of the projection, so that the left side would come in front become yellow.

But of course, it is the axis that rotate, and what has been drawn is not affected by later transformations. So what really happens is that  red is drawn in front, then the z-axis goes on the right side and yellow is painted there, and so on for the rest of the faces.